# combining similar rows with two same values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables: users, products and reviews. I'm trying to get form a table that would show products that have gotten the same review from different users, the users who reviewed it and what review it got.
Here are the tables and the output I'm looking for:

```
Users  
uid  uname
1    name1  
2    name2  
3    name3  
4    name4

Products
pid  pname  
1    A  
2    B  
3    C  
4    D  

Reviews   
pid  uid  grade  
1    1    3  
1    2    2  
1    3    3  
2    1    4  
3    2    1  
2    2    4  
4    3    1
```

**Desired output:**

```
uname  uname2  pname  grade  
name1  name3   A      3  
name3  name1   A      3  
name1  name2   B      4  
name2  name1   B      4
```

Comment: How many column should the resultant table? In your example it seems that you want to create columns for 2 users and their review for a given product.

Comment: The output Columns are uname, unname 2, pname, grade. So 4 columns. There are two similar kind of users at maximum as one can see in the table Reviews (1st & 3rd row, 4th & 6th row). So there would be total 4 rows in the output. It is kind of simple task but I'm stuck.

Comment: To clarify requirements, what would the output be like in the example if there were three users with the same product and grade match? Would there still only be columns for two users or would a third column be added?

Comment: That's a good question David. I'm quite sure we don't have to worry about that because this is just a basic exercise at my database course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some overly complicated answers here.

Its pretty simple using a self join like this:

```
select u1.uname, u2.uname, p.pname, r1.grade
from review r1
join review r2 on r2.pid=r1.pid and r2.grade=r1.grade and r2.uid<>r1.uid
join products p on p.pid=r1.pid
join users u1 on u1.uid=r1.uid
join users u2 on u2.uid=r2.uid
order by pname, r1.grade, u1.uname, u2.uname
```

Result:

```
uname   uname1  pname   grade
name1   name3   A       3
name3   name1   A       3
name1   name2   B       4
name2   name1   B       4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select users.uname, reviews.grade, products.pname from products
join reviews on products.id = reviews.pid
join users on users.id = reviews.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a self-join like this -

```
with combined as 
    (select (select uname from users where uid = r.uid), 
        (select pname from products where pid = r.pid), 
        r.grade,
        r.uid 
        from reviews r)
select c1.uname as name1, c2.uname as name2, c1.pname, c1.grade
    from combined c1, combined c2
    where c1.grade = c2.grade
    and c1.pname = c2.pname
    and c1.uid <> c2.uid;
```